# Plus 1 hour and 1 day in date using java 8 apis

Tags: java, date, java-8

I have this code to add 1 hour or 1 day in date Java 8, but doesn´t work

```
    String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    java.text.SimpleDateFormat format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
    Date parse = format.parse("2017-01-01 13:00:00");
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(parse.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
    ldt.plusHours(1);
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    Date te = Date.from(zdt.toInstant());
```

What´s wrong? The code shows: Sun Jan 01 13:00:00 BRST 2017

Comment: Check the API for LocalDateTime; you do not re-assign your variable but the javadoc says:

Return:
a LocalDateTime based on this date-time with the hours added, not null

See:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#plusHours-long-

Comment: I need an example to add hour

Comment: Change your line from `ldt.plusHours(1);` to `ldt = ldt.plusHours(1);` Because here `ldt` is not a mutable object. So, it is actually adding the hours but not updating them. You have to assgin the value explicitly.

Comment: As an aside, since you can use the modern Java date and time API, go all-in and stay away from `Date` and in particular the troublesome `SimpleDateFormat`: `LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("2017-01-01 13:00:00", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));`.

Comment: Do not mix troublesome old legacy `Date` class with replacement modern java.time classes.

Answer (score 5):

LocalDateTime is immutable and returns a new LocalDateTime when you call methods on it.

So you must call

```
ldt = ldt.plusHours(1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the issue that you don't use the result of your date manipulation (`ldt = ldt.plusHours(1)`), you don't really need to go via a LocalDateTime for this operation.

I would simply use an OffsetDateTime since you don't care about time zones:

```
OffsetDateTime odt = parse.toInstant().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
odt = odt.plusDays(1).plusHours(1);
Date te = Date.from(odt.toInstant());
```

You could even stick to using `Instant`s:

```
Instant input = parse.toInstant();
Date te = Date.from(input.plus(1, DAYS).plus(1, HOURS));
```

(with an `import static java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.*;`)

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime.parse(                            // Parse input string that lacks any indication of offset-from-UTC or time zone.
    "2017-01-01 13:00:00".replace( " " , "T" )  // Convert to ISO 8601 standard format.
).atZone(                                       // Assign a time zone to render a meaningful ZonedDateTime object, an actual point on the timeline.  
    ZoneId.systemDefault()                      // The Question uses default time zone. Beware that default can change at any moment during runtime. Better to specify an expected/desired time zone generally.
).plus(
    Duration.ofDays( 1L ).plusHours( 1L )       // Add a span of time.
)
```

## Details

Do not mix the troublesome old legacy classes `Date` and `Calendar` with the modern java.time classes. Use only java.time, avoiding the legacy classes.

The java.time classes use the ISO 8601 standard formats by default when parsing and generating strings. Convert your input string by replacing the SPACE in the middle with a `T`.

```
String input = "2017-01-01 13:00:00".replace( " " , "T" ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

A`LocalDateTime` does not represent an actual moment, not a point on the timeline. It has no real meaning until you assign a time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // I recommend specifying the desired/expected zone rather than relying on current default. 
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

A `Duration` represents a span of time not attached to the timeline.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofDays( 1L ).plusHours( 1L ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtLater = zdt.plus( d ) ;
```